# How to check for errors in resolve using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

Im using a resolve in ui-router and a promise in my controller, but cant figure out how to check if a 422 / 500 error is returned and show a different message.

here is my code:

```
    .state('rated', {
                url: "/top-rated",
                templateUrl: "/assets/views/us/wine_grid_rated.html",
                controller: 'ratingsController',
                    resolve : {
                    ratingsData: function(userRatings) { 
                            return userRatings.list();
                        }
                    }
            })


$scope.ratings = [];
            $scope.message = "Loading your wines...";
            $scope.loading = true;
            $scope.response = ratingsData; // Bind a scope model directly to the resource

            console.log('response'+ratingsData);

             ratingsData.$promise.then(function(ratingsData) {
                $scope.message = '';
                $scope.loading = false;
                console.log(ratingsData.userItems);
                if (ratingsData.userItems == '' || ratingsData.userItems == undefined) {
                    $scope.message = "Sorry, it appears that you have not reviewed any wines on the website.";
                }
                else {
                    $scope.message = '';
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    angular.forEach(ratingsData.userItems, function (item) {
                        item.color = item.product.colourId;
                        $scope.ratings.push(item);
                    });
                    $scope.setPagination();
                }

            });

services.factory("userRatings", function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/user/ratings/:action/:item", 
        {}, 
        {
            'list': {method: 'GET', params: {action: 'list'}, isArray: false},
            'save': {method: 'PUT', params: {item: '@item'}},
            'remove': {method: 'DELETE', params: {item: '@item'}},
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Please show the code for the userRatings service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$q` to create your own deferred promise and resolve it yourself.

```
resolve : {
  ratingsData: [ "userRatings", "$q", function( userRatings, $q ) { 
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    userRatings.list().then(
      function onSuccess( data ) {
        deferred.resolve( data );
      },
      function onError( error ) {
        deferred.resolve( error );
      }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
  } ]
}
```

Comment: How do I integrate this into my controller? I've been reading about interceptors - coulnd't I use an interceptor too?

Comment: You don't have to integrate it in your controller. Resolves happen before the controller loads, so you would handle the error, and redirect to another page etc.

Comment: Ah cool - do you handle the error in the controller though or right there? I might look into interceptors, feels a bit cleaner.

Comment: @jrutter If you want to handle the whole thing in your controller, don't use the resolver. Just inject the userRatings service into your controller and resolve the promise there.

Comment: No, I definitely want to use the resolver. I'll see if I can use an interceptor?